# How can I group results in multpiple conditions subgroups with eloquent laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a product table and I am trying to make a query with eloquent in which I group the results into five subgroups depending on conditions.
Each subgroup will show the total number of rows that meet this condition.

```
DB::table(Product::TABLE_NAME)->select(
    DB::raw("prize"),
    DB::raw("count(*) as total")
)
->groupBy('prize')->get();
```

I don't know where put the conditions.

I expect this output:

```
id_group | total |
------------------
1        | 34    |
2        | 46    |
3        | 126   |
```

id_group represents each condition:

```
1 - prize = null
2 - prize = 0
3 - prize > 0
```

**Solution**:
*I've got this, but I don't know if is the more efficient way or if exists other way to do it:*

```
DB::table(Product::TABLE_NAME)->select(
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE
        WHEN prize IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 1"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE
        WHEN prize = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 2"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE
        WHEN prize > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 3")
)->get();
```

Comment: I don't see a more efficient way.

Comment: Thx Jonas for answering me! One question, there are a way to do this in eloquent without using raw query?

Comment: Only by executing separate queries for each case. I assume that's not what you want.

Comment: Just what I thought. Thx @JonasStaudenmeir